# Search Xively feed id in javascript

Tags: javascript, xively

Is it possible to get all the feed id from a specific location in javascript? I already read some of xively javascript documentation http://xively.github.io/xively-js/docs/ but I still can't find the answer of my problem.

In the xively I also found some information about finding a feed https://xively.com/dev/docs/api/data/read/all_feeds/ , but I really have no idea to apply this on javascript.

Thanks,

Comment: Location as in Geo-location?

Comment: yes, I think we can only search based on geo-location. It will be better if I can just set a location such as Amsterdam, or any other city but I think that's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `xively.feed.list` methods, adding the `lat`, `lon`, `radius` and `distance` parameters.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rPuVw/